# Not able to make a class in Python and output it to excel

Tags: python-3.x, inventory-management

I'm fairly new in `Python` and working in a inventory management position.
One important thing in inventory management is calculating the safety stock.

So, this is what I'm trying to achieve.

I have imported a file with 3 columns; `FR`, `sigma` and `LT` for 3 rows. See hereunder the code and the output:

code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("Desktop\\TestPython4.xlsx")
xcol=["FR","sigma","LT"]
x=df[xcol].values
```

output:
[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdCR4.png)

To calculate the safety stock, I have the following (simplified) formula of it;

```
CDF(FR)*sigma*sqrt(LT)
```

where `CDF` is the cumulative distribution function of the normal distribution and `FR` is a number between 0 and 1 (thus the well-knowned z-value is the output).

I want to output a the file with an extra column that displays the safety stock.
For this I made a class `safetystock` with the following code:

```
class Safetystock:
def __init__(self,FR,sigma,LT):
    self.FR = FR
    self.sigma = sigma
    self.LT = LT
    pass

def calculate():
    SS=st.norm.ppf(FR)
    return print(SS*sigma*np.sqrt(LT))
    pass
```

Then I made the variable: "output"

```
Output = Safetystock(df.FR,df.sigma,df.LT)
```

I said that the data in the file needs to be taken into account.
Then I added a column to `df`, named `output` that needs to contain the variable "Output":

```
df["output"]=Output
```

Now, when I want to call `df`, it gives me this:

[actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlisa.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers,

Steven

Comment: It's working exactly like should be, you are saving class instances on Dataframe as output. What do you mean by variable output? BTW pass on __init__? what is the reason?

Comment: variable output= output per row (so 3 outputs which displays the safety stock based on the FR, sigma and LT). Pass on init: don't remember it. But even without it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st

df = pd.read_excel("Desktop\\TestPython4.xlsx")
df["output"] = st.norm.ppf(df.FR)*df.sigma*np.sqrt(df.LT)
```

Comment: But how do I do it when I want to use a class?